# SeekBarPreferences are changing but not visually

Tags: android

I've been trying to work this out for 2 days now and I have absolutely no idea how to fix it.

Essentially, I have a service that listens for changes in a ListView (via a BroadcastReceiver) and updates several SeekBarPreferences accordingly via editor.putInt("SeekBarPreference", value).commit();. Now everything works as it should and it returns the correct values BUT it wont change the seekbarpreferences visually. If I restart the service (press back and then click on the relevant option) they change to the correct positions. Or even if I rotate the device they change.
I guess my question is; Is there any way to manually "refresh" the 'look' of the preferences?

Thanks!

(I know there are similar questions on here, but none of them really have a solution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lame way I sometimes fall back on is to relaunch the activity.  Create an intent for the current activity and launch it. Two lines of code. Don't know if its a practical solution for your problem, but its worked in various situations for me.

Comment: I've actually been trying to do this, but it's a Service with a preference screen. I can stop the service just fine but I've no idea how to relaunch a preference screen.

Answer (score 0):

did you try `invalidate()` or `requestlayout()` on that view?

Comment: The problem is they're not in a layout. All my sliders and everything are in a preference menu.

Comment: you can use getview() to get the relevant view

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get the seekbars updating on the ponSharedPreferenceChanged listener by clearing the preferences

```
    PreferenceScreen prefScreen = getPreferenceScreen();
        prefScreen.removeAll();
```

loading the xml again

```
    addPreferencesFromResource(...etc.
```

Then re-sending the broadcast to update everything

It works, but it isn't very elegant. Thanks to everyone for helping!